# 'mat-form-field' is not a known element - Angular 4 & Angular Material 2

Tags: angular, typescript, module, angular-material2

In my angular application, I have a `presentation.module` that holds all components. I have created a `shared-material.module` containing all angular material 2 modules used in the whole app. I have imported it in the previous `presentation.module`. In my `app.module`, I have imported the `presentation.module`.

The `app.module` have in its declaration `app.component`, `header.component` and `footer.component`

Here is my `app.module` :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    // Layer's modules
    PresentationModule,
    BusinessDelegateModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my `presentation.module` :

```
const modules = [
  SharedMaterialModule,
  SharedModule,
  HomePresentationModule,
  SecurityPresentationModule,
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [...modules],
  exports: [...modules]
})
export class PresentationModule {
}
```

The source code of `shared-material.module` :

```
// updated: Before, i have just imported these modules without re-exporting them.
const materialModules = [
  MatButtonModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatTooltipModule
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [...materialModules],
  exports: [...materialModules],
  declarations: []
})
export class SharedMaterialModule {
}
```

As you can see bellow, I have registered a `security-presentation.module`, here is its source code:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    SecurityRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    EmailConfirmationComponent,
    PasswordResetComponent
  ]
})
export class SecurityPresentationModule {
}
```

My problem is when I attempt to use `mat-input-field` in the `login.component` (in the `security-presentation.module` ), i got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-form-field' is not a known element
```

But other angular material 2 components work fine in the `app.component`, `header.component` and `footer.component`:

`app.component.html`

```
<div>

  <app-header></app-header>

  <div class="main-container">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>

  <app-footer></app-footer>

</div>
```

Should I import `shared-material.module` in each presentation module or is there a way to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue and have yet to find a solution. :( Have you been able to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because your shared module should first import the material modules :

```js
const materialModules = [
    MatButtonModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTooltipModule
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [...materialModules],
  exports: [...materialModules],
  declarations: []
})
export class SharedMaterialModule {
}
```

Comment: I got the same errors, i have already added this `imports` property.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't there in your code. Did you put it in your presentation module too ? If so, it would be great if you could add it to your post, because it reallys can get confusing as you can see.

Comment: I have updated my post. I don't understand why some material modules work fine inside `app.component`, `header.component` and `footer.component` and doesn't work in other views even I imported them in the shared module.

Comment: Hum wait : what is your current version of angular Material ? mat-form-field is very recent, maybe you're not up to date ? try using md-form-field to see ? And do other components work into the presentation module, or are they all in error  ?

Comment: I am using angular material `^5.0.0-rc0`.

Comment: so pretty new. Do buttons work in the presentation module ?

Comment: All component in the presentation module have this error. Only the root module components work fine

Comment: I see. The presentation module has no import, is that normal or did you forget it ?